# Load more projects with blob images in it

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, blob

I am displaying projects on my website, but not to show all projects at once I am using a "show more" button that loads in more projects with ajax. But I can't seem to print out the image of my loaded project because it is a blob image. The other problem is that I don't know how to print out 2 projects at once, now I only load in 1 project at a time.

// AJAX

```
$('#show-more').on("click", function(e){  
  e.preventDefault();

  var lastID = $("#projects ul").children().last().attr('id');

  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/show-more.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"lastID": lastID},
    dataType:"json"
  })
  .done(function( msg ){
    if (msg.succes == true) {

        $('#projects ul').append(

            "<li class='project' id='"+msg.project.id+"'>"+
                "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64, "+msg.project.image+"' alt='work'>"+
                "<div class='mask fade'>"+
                        "<h4>"+msg.project.titel+"</h4>"+
                        "<p>"+msg.project.text+"</p>"+
                "</div>"+
            "</li>"
        );
    }
  });
});
```

// show-more.php

```
<?php 
try {
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","portfolio");
    $lastID = $_POST["lastID"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM work WHERE filter = 'webdesign' AND id < ".$lastID." ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 2";

    $results = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $response["project"] = $result;
    }
    $response["succes"] = true;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $response["succes"] = false;
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple results save the rows in an array, also base64 encode the image data

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $result["image"] = base64_encode($result["image"]);
    $response["project"][] = $result;
}
```

then loop through the results

```
$.each(msg.project, function(){
    $('#projects ul').append(

        "<li class='project' id='"+this.id+"'>"+
            "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64, "+this.image+"' alt='work'>"+
            "<div class='mask fade'>"+
                    "<h4>"+this.titel+"</h4>"+
                    "<p>"+this.text+"</p>"+
            "</div>"+
        "</li>"
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should store your image as a file not blob and store the path in database so that you can easily use it. Btw base64 would not work if the data is not encoded by base64